# Should I create a new array or use array.clear?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of data that gets zeroed out from time to time. To do that, should I instantiate a new array, or use the Array.Clear method?

For instance,

```
int workingSet = new int[5000];

// Other code here

workingSet = new int[5000];
// or
Array.Clear(workingSet, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: Will the new array always have the same number of elements as old one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you make a new array instead of an old one, C# will:

1. Make the old array eligible for garbage collection, and eventually deallocate it
2. Allocate a new array
3. Fill the new array with zeros.

When you keep an old array, C# will

1. Fill the old array with zeros.

Everything else being equal, the second approach is more efficient.

Comment: I would say not always...for small arrays the first approach is faster AFAIK....but not sure really!

Comment: The second approach may also keeps the array alive during various GCs, moving it to an older generation.  This might increase the amount of heavy, global GCs.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is being referenced in many places, it is safer to use `Clear()`, as it guarantees that all instances of the same array continue to reference the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Array clear usually has better performance when you have a large array....I mean like thousands of elements. Otherwise for small arrays just use new. If you use this array in other places in your code e.g. between threads, you should use clear to make sure everythread will work with zeroed/defaulted array

you can easily check it yourself with some stopwatch mechanism or profiling tools