# C# Reinitialize an array multiple times inside loop

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, loops, initialization

I am currently working on a project handling multiple byte arrays. In one scenario it could happen that an array is being reinitialized multiple times in a while loop. The only reason this happens is because the application is receiving read requests, but the information received is incorrect.

I have to have a 'clean' byte array to write back to the device indicating that the information was incorrect. The device being read from has the tendency to jump into a 'loop' where it keeps sending that 'incorrect' data until it is interacted with which is not a problem per say. Just know the device spamming read requests is not a problem at this moment in time and will be dealt with in the future.

My question is this:
**Are there any performance/coding issues when reinitializing an array inside a while loop for an extended period of time? 10000+ iterations for example**

Code example:

```
byte[] array = new byte[500]

while(condition)
{
   // Some work

   array = new byte[500]
   
   Thread.Sleep(100);

   // Some work
}
```

Comment: Maybe this suits your needs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-5.0

Comment: This seems to be helpful aswell - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175124/should-i-create-a-new-array-or-use-array-clear

Comment: @RandRandom The ArrayPool is looking to be the answer I need, I am going to play around with it and come back to let you know.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(100);` is by far *longer* then either `new byte[500]` or `Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - with `10000+` iterations as described in the post this would sum up to roughly 16 minutes sleep time, I believe OP just wanted to show "some code" is there.

Comment: If you want to know if the code performs adequately for your needs then *run the code and see how well it performs, and if that meets your needs*.  We can't know whether or not it meets your needs as we don't know how you're using this code or what your performance requirements are.

Answer (score -1):

If the array dont change you can simply clear the Array (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=net-5.0):

```
Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);
```

To save performance you can also run your function asynchronous.

Comment: The OP tagged `[multitasking]` so I feel clearing a shared array might be a wholly bad idea.